# The flag pop up on heavily downvoted answers has grey text

Tags: bug, status-completed, flags, design

1. Go to any random heavily downvoted answer
2. Click on the `flag` button
3. .  [image: Profit!!!]

Is this [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign)?

This is still happening, over a year later, and with work having been done updating the flagging options.

Comment: The FHC countdown time is running...

Comment: In addition, the flag popup on heavily downvoted _questions_ is _not_ gray, supporting John Rudy's post. I just saw this behavior myself a few minutes ago.

Comment: This is still occurring in Review as evidenced in http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97472/flag-popup-in-review-is-translucent-for-non-hidden-ignored-tags

Comment: I had a thought as to how the situation could be alleviated during `Review` times -- if there were a setting with which we could turn off favorites/ignored tags feature just for the Review stream, this would be less of a problem.

Comment: @jonsca Agreed, having questions grayed out in review is pointless.

Comment: There are quite a few highly downvoted answers on which to test this behavior [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1/jeff-atwood#anpage_144-ansort_votes).  Alternatively, search for [\[status-declined\] votes:100](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bstatus-declined%5D+votes%3A100).

Answer (score 21):

Bumping this question, because the problem is still present. I think it is actually a problematic bug -- I initially thought that the flagging dialogue was disabled for some reason (e.g. because the answer had already been deleted).

[image: Flag dialogue box faded]

I can't believe this would be difficult to fix -- something like this would correct it, I think:

```
.popup {
    color: #000;
}
```

Comment: I dislike that proposed fix, it means we would have to maintain another rule per site

Answer (score 15):

Was about to bug report this as well.  Only my example had a narwhal.
[image]

Comment: I wish mine had a narwhal.

Comment: That's either a pearl necklace or some serious overbite

Comment: @AdamDavis: Throw me a link and I'll narwhalify it.

Comment: For the unbelievers: A Narwhal is the obvious crossbreed between a meremaid and a unicorn. Narwals do exist, so both meremaids and unicorns must exist.

Comment: They are not overbites; they are love bites. (I guess the narwhal has a fiancè.)

Comment: Wait, how did you get 7 downvotes and an accept in 38 seconds?!?

Comment: this should also be fixed

Comment: @Will has a net vote of -7, yet is still accepted. Cool. :)

Comment: @Gamecat You are a cross between a game and a cat, and you exist. Therefore, all of the following creatures must exist: the horse [and his boy], the unicorn, the mermaid, and the walrus-game-cat-waffle. This is the reason I have 2+k rep on SO: my superior logic and inability to post completely tangential, sporadic, numerous, heavily edited, or wordy comments containing several references, none of which I expect to be picked up, and hard to parse sentences composed of infallible grammar. And also... I forgot. [Whatever I forgot. I forgot what I forgot. Otherwise, I wouldn't have forgotten it!!]

Comment: (Sorry @Won'tಠ_ಠ for the last comment. :) On another side note, it used up *exactly* all the characters allotted for a comment.)

Answer (score 12):

[status-not-by-design](/questions/tagged/status-not-by-design)

We were setting "color" on the top level post div, the flag was inheriting it. I changed it so we target `.downvoted-answer .post-text`

I just change a bunch of style sheets. This should be resloved.

Another bug was lurking ... on many SE 2.0 sites the downvoted styling was overridden. That is also fixed.

If every single stylesheet on all our sites breaks ... it is my fault

Comment: to be deployed later

Answer (score 5):

Based on the Web Developer Toolbar in Firefox, it appears that the Flag Reasons box is a child element of the `<td>` which contains the post. As a result, although the style information piece in the toolbar wasn't picking up font colors at all for me, I'm going to *guess* that the Flag Reasons box inherits its font color from the post itself, so if the post font color changes, so does it. And of course, the post font color does in fact change when the post is heavily downvoted.

Whether or not that's "correct" behavior is debatable, but that's how it appears to be happening.

Comment: I figured so much, and I'm reporting it as I imagine that behavior to be more likely to be the result of somebody forgetting a special case in the CSS than a specific design decision for a specific rare situation.

Answer (score 1):

I'm getting this too. It can be annoying, as if another transparent entry falls on top of a button in the dialog, I can't click it.

[image: No Narwhal]

Comment: This is not the same problem.

Comment: @KevinVermeer Oh, I initially opened this as a new question, but was informed it was a dupe.

Comment: It is the same problem, the dialog inherits the style properties of the post. Although the fact that you can't click some of the options is likely a separate issue. I'm not sure off-hand why that would happen here...hmm.

Comment: Whoops!  I saw black text and transparency, and assumed that it was different from the gray text and opacity.  You're right, it's the same problem.

Comment: @TimStone You can see on the example posted that `How to avoid using membership provider?` is on top of the dialog, and I wouldn't be able to flag this as spam as a result (I'd have to close the dialog, scroll, and reopen it).