# Flag popup in review is translucent for non-hidden ignored tags

Tags: bug, design, review

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [The flag pop up on heavily downvoted answers has grey text](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40111/the-flag-pop-up-on-heavily-downvoted-answers-has-grey-text)

I'm using Firefox 5.0, latest version as I write this, on Windows XP.

I have [iphone](/questions/tagged/iphone) as an ignored tag and I do not have the "hide ignored tags" option selected in preferences, so [iphone](/questions/tagged/iphone) questions in /review show as translucent, as expected.

However, when clicking to flag a question with one of my ignored tags from the /review page (without expanding the answer), the flagging pop-up is also translucent:

[image: Stack Overflow review example]

Translucency aside, it is covering the text in the box it originates from, so I assume the problem is that it is inheriting the opacity of a parent element.