# Review New User Posts Ignored Tag Screen Has Transparency Problems

Tags: bug, flags, 10k-tools, ignored-tags

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [The flag pop up on heavily downvoted answers has grey text](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40111/the-flag-pop-up-on-heavily-downvoted-answers-has-grey-text)
>   [Flag popup in review is translucent for non-hidden ignored tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97472/flag-popup-in-review-is-translucent-for-non-hidden-ignored-tags)

Because certain tags are marked as ignored, when I go to the Review New User Posts under the Tools menu, it displays the sub-menu also transparently which is very hard to read. Can we fix this?

[image]

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40111/the-flag-pop-up-on-heavily-downvoted-answers-has-grey-text (it's a different part of the interface in that question, but it's the same problem, and I had put the bounty up to change the way the Review was behaving).

Comment: Which is not to say that I don't consider this question important, just the opposite.  I'm not sure if the bug got enough upvotes to be considered, though.