# Flagging on low quality/dimmed answer dialog text color dimmed too

Tags: bug, design

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [The flag pop up on heavily downvoted answers has grey text](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40111/the-flag-pop-up-on-heavily-downvoted-answers-has-grey-text)

When I go to flag a low quality and dimmed answer, the flag dialog's text color is dimmed too.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug related to how color is handled for the Peer Pressure badge.  When your post qualifies for that badge (mainly -3 votes) the text grays out.  The color follows on to the flagging dialog.