# Voting on withdrawn moderator nominations shows unreadable message

Tags: bug, status-completed, voting, election

Two bugs related to the [SO moderator election](https://stackoverflow.com/election) (noticed wth Firefox 8).

Voting on withdrawn nominations results in showing a message box "Voting is locked for this candidate". The box is hard to read, I think because the arrows and vote counter are transparent, the box is transparent too.

Related to this is the following case, where two withdrawn nominations are displayed next to each other: The message box for the upper nomination is not clickable* - it won't disappear. Voting on the lower one creates a box that does disappear when clicked.

* A small area at the top, that is still inside the container, is still clickable.

[image: "Voting is locked for this candidate" message]

---

**Update** - As also mentioned in the comments it's caused by the table row's opacity.
There's this inline JavaScript that sets the opacity.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () { $('#post-8043315').css({ opacity: 0.2 });
    $('.withdraw-date').css({ opacity: 1 }); })
</script>
```

The problem is, that even if the message box would use `opacity: 1`, it won't be more opaque than the parent `tr` element. I guess `.withdraw-date` should be fully opaque too - but is not for the same reason.

Solution? Make only some of the elements transparent. At first glance I say only `td.post-signature.owner`, `span.vote-up-off`, `span.vote-count-post` and `span.vote-down-off` should be transparent.

This would also cause the separation line to be visible again, which should be there imho, since the post (even if it was withdrawn) ends and the next one begins.

When the opacity issue is fixed, the upper message box is be closable again.

Comment: Repro with FF7/Win7 (last night, actually).

Comment: The overlay is probably just getting the same transparent styling as the div of the widthdrawn post. Does this happen when voting on "greyed out" low voted posts on questions too?

Comment: @BenBrocka yes. EDIT I misread, I thought you were referring to [grayed out flag options](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40111/the-flag-pop-up-on-heavily-downvoted-answers-has-grey-text).

Comment: The CSS probably just needs to add `opacity:1;` for the voting pop up, at least to fix the visual issue. Can't check cause I can't see the withdrawn posts apparently. Edit: actually I did find a post to test and I don't see opacity in the CSS.

Comment: @PopularDemand similar issue of an overzealous selector it looks like, though not exactly what I was referring to.

Comment: According to Firebug: "Inherited from `tr#post-8043315`: `element.style { opacity: 0.2; }`"

Comment: The style is applied directly to the div in HTML, not the CSS, `opacity:0.2`. giving the `error-notification` class `opacity:1` should fix it. Edit: @PopularDemand now why didn't Chrome's Inspect element tell me that?! I had to look through the HTML.

Comment: Why is someone voting to close this as 'not constructive'?  It seems like a perfectly legitimate bug report to me.  If you disagree that this is a bug that should be fixed, downvote the question - don't vote to close it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was fixed by just hiding the up/down voting arrows if the candidate had withdrawn; the score is still available, as is the fetching of up/down vote counts.

Comment: Available in the next build, sometime in the next 24 hours.