# Flagging popup for a highly downvoted answer also appears opaque/transparent

Tags: bug, status-completed, flags

[image: opaque]

As you can see, this answer has -3 thus making it opaque/transparent. However, that transparency also carries over to the popup for flagging.

What really gets me is that the top part with the question, description, and slider bar shows through this transparency, but none of the comments and the box below that show through. Magic?

**Note:** This is occurring (for me) in the review panel. I haven't tested in a regular question.

Comment: Hmmm. waffles marked this [completed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40111/the-flag-pop-up-on-heavily-downvoted-answers-has-grey-text) a while back.

Comment: @Michael: Perhaps I should have mentioned this is in the *review* panel? Maybe some new style is overriding again?

Comment: This happens in a regular question too (found your report when I came here to report the same thing).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jin pushed a fix for this that'll go into the next build: each section is given opacity rather than cascading from on the parent `<div>`, and the popup won't be in a targetted area.